# Ring Homomorphism Question

Tags: ring-homomorphism

Let $f:F_1 → F_2$ be a ring homomorphism between fields $F_1, F_2$.
(a) Show that if $f(1)=0$ then $f=0$.
(b) Show that if $f(1)\ne0$ then $f$ is injective.

Hi, I'm not too sure how to do this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The only ideals of a field $F$ are $(0)$ and $F$. Also, the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal of the domain.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

All ring homomorphisms send the identity of the first ring to the identity of the second ring. Since $f(1)=0$, we know that 0 is the both the multiplicative identity and the additive identity of the field $F_2$. That implies that $F_2$ is the trivial field of one element so $f$ maps all elements of $F_1$ to $0$.\

The second part is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957916/homomorphisms-between-fields-are-injective).

Comment: I would guess that ring homomorphisms as the OP means do not need to preserve the identity, as $\{0\}$ is not a field. Your argument that $f$ sends all $F_1$ to $0$ is not quite complete if one takes this definition of ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose that $f(1) = 0,$ and let $x\in F_1.$ Then $$f(x) = f(1\cdot x) = f(1)\cdot f(x) = 0\cdot f(x) = 0,$$ so that $f$ is identically $0.$
2. Suppose that $f(1)\neq 0,$ and let $x\in F_1^\times.$ We wish to show that $f(x)\in F_2^\times,$ so that the only element of $F_1$ mapped to $0$ by $f$ is $0,$ which will imply that $f$ is injective. Observe that
   $$
   f(1) = f(x\cdot x^{-1}) = f(x)\cdot f(x)^{-1}.
   $$
   It follows that $f(x)\neq 0,$ as $f(1)\neq 0.$

A much quicker proof of both these results is indicated by azif00's comment: the kernel of any ring homomorphism (unital or nonunital) is an ideal of the domain. The only ideals of a field are $(0)$ and the entire field itself. We have $1\in\ker f$ if and only if $f(1) = 0,$ so that $f(1) = 0$ if and only if $\ker f = F_1,$ which implies that $\ker f = (0)$ (and hence $f$ is injective) if $f(1)\neq 0.$